# MVC Web App Error HTTP 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor

Im doing an MVC tutorial and Im in the part of doing a really basic web app.

This is the Controller inside my Controller folder:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace FirstMVCApplication.Controllers
{
    public class HomeContoller : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /HomeContoller/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;

            ViewBag.Greeting =
            hour < 12
            ? "Good Morning. Time is" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()
            : "Good Afternoon. Time is " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my View inside View Folder:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @ViewBag.Greeting (<b>From Index View</b>)
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Im using Razor.

And when I execute it It returns an HTTP 404 resource not found. It is an Empty Web MVC-4 Application.

EDIT
RouteConfig

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace FirstMVCApplication
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This view must stay inside the Views/Home folder. You should post the route config file and the url that you are tupying in the browser.

Comment: http://localhost:"Port"/

Comment: Two points here: 1- 4XX errors, means that you (the user, not the server) did something wrong. 2- 404 =  the resource you are requesting not found, may be you are using a wrong url. Please, show us the url displayed in the browser

Comment: It is http ://localhost :55171/

Comment: Your view should be in `/Views/Home` and is named `Index.cshtml`. You can try the more explicit route `http://localhost:55171/Home/Index`. And you also recompiled, cleared your cache, and killed the development web server in the system tray?

Answer (score 0):

Delete this @{ Layout = null; } from the Layout.cshtml  file you posted here

Add  @RenderBody() to Layout.cshtml file you posted here

In the Index.cshtml file which you do have here. Add at the top of the page  file

@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml"; }

Comment: My view is called `Index.cshtml` so you say I write `@RenderBody()` and delete `@{ Layout = null; }`

What about the Index.cshtml file? I have only one view.

You say `/Views/Shared/` but the view is inside the `Views` folder and that is it.

Do I have to create another folder called `Shared` inside my `Views` folder? also, where do I write `@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml"; }`